# How can I generate HTML code coverage reports with new cabal?

Tags: haskell, code-coverage, cabal, cabal-new, haskell-program-coverage

Running `stack test --coverage` generates a nice HTML report showing what lines your test suite covers. How can I achieve the same thing using `cabal new-test`?

I'm able to pass `--enable-coverage` to generate a `.tix` file but I'm not sure what to run on the `.tix` file to generate the HTML report. I'm pretty sure it involves `hpc` but I haven't been able to work out the right command.

I have the standard Cabal configuration of my application being a library, with a test-suite for that library.

Answer (score 3):

It appears it's as easy as passing `--enable-coverage` to `cabal new-test`. I had previously been running tests with `cabal new-run test:test` to workaround some limitations of `new-test` (e.g. lacking streaming and colors), so the fix is to use `new-test` instead of `new-run`.

Answer (score 1):

Cabal 3.6 should be able to generate the HPC report. There is one caveat; this error may appear:

```
Error:
Internal libraries only supported with per-component builds.
Per-component builds were disabled because program coverage is enabled
```

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/6440

To avoid the error, add to `cabal.project`:

```
package *
  coverage: True
  library-coverage: True
```

then `cabal test` (without `--enable-coverage`). The report should be somewhere in `dist-newstyle`.

Comment: Where do we find it in `dist-newstyle`?

Comment: Search for the `.mix`, `.tix`, or `.html` files. Here is the result for the `text` library: `dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.6.4/text-2.1.1/t/tests/hpc/vanilla/html/hpc_index.html`